# What trimotor is this model?

Tags: aircraft-identification

What trimotor is this model?

[image: (own work)]
(own work)

Comment: Are you sure that's a real airplane? The vertical stabilizer seem far too small.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe it's the French Couzinet 71 'Arc-en-Ciel'
https://www.hydroretro.net/etudegh/arc-en-ciel_atlantique_vol1.pdf

Comment: Not quite - I think it is the [Couzinet 70](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Couzinet_70). The radiators of the model look like those of the Hispano-Suiza engines of the Arc-en-ciel III. The linked PDF is a great find!

Comment: What an interesting but tragic story...